# Angular ui router unit testing (states to urls)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having some trouble unit testing the router in my application, which is built on the Angular ui router. What I want to test is whether state transitions change the URL appropriately (there will be more complicated tests later, but this is where I'm starting.)

Here is the relevant portion of my application code:

```
angular.module('scrapbooks')
 .config( function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('splash', {
       url: "/splash/",
       templateUrl: "/app/splash/splash.tpl.html",
       controller: "SplashCtrl"
    })
 })
```

And the testing code:

```
it("should change to the splash state", function(){
  inject(function($state, $rootScope){
     $rootScope.$apply(function(){
       $state.go("splash");
     });
     expect($state.current.name).to.equal("splash");
  })
})
```

Similar questions on Stackoverflow (and the official ui router test code) suggest wrapping the $state.go call in $apply should be enough. But I've done that and the state is still not updating. $state.current.name remains empty.

Comment: Okay, figured it out (sort of.) If I define a mock router, with inline templates instead of template URLs, the transition succeeds.

Comment: Can you post your working code as the answer?

Comment: I asked this question almost a year ago. My view now is that the best way to solve this problem is to use the [ng-template-to-js preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) in Karma.

Comment: More specifically: the issue is that if the template download fails in the test (i.e. because there is no server), the state change will fail. However, unless you are watching for the $stateChangeError event, you will not see the error. Nevertheless, because the state change fails, $state.current.name will not be updated.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Been having this issue as well, and finally figured out how to do it.

Here is a sample state:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('myState', {
        url: '/state/:id',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        resolve: {
            data: ['myService', function(service) {
                return service.findAll();
            }]
        }
    });
}]);
```

The unit test below will cover testing the URL w/ params, and executing the resolves which inject its own dependencies:

```
describe('myApp/myState', function() {

  var $rootScope, $state, $injector, myServiceMock, state = 'myState';

  beforeEach(function() {

    module('myApp', function($provide) {
      $provide.value('myService', myServiceMock = {});
    });

    inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $state = _$state_;
      $injector = _$injector_;

      // We need add the template entry into the templateCache if we ever
      // specify a templateUrl
      $templateCache.put('template.html', '');
    })
  });

  it('should respond to URL', function() {
    expect($state.href(state, { id: 1 })).toEqual('#/state/1');
  });

  it('should resolve data', function() {
    myServiceMock.findAll = jasmine.createSpy('findAll').and.returnValue('findAll');
    // earlier than jasmine 2.0, replace "and.returnValue" with "andReturn"

    $state.go(state);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);

    // Call invoke to inject dependencies and run function
    expect($injector.invoke($state.current.resolve.data)).toBe('findAll');
  });
});
```

Comment: Great post. I am stuck as my state always says it expects null. Please suggest why this happens.

Comment: Great post, time saver if you're using strings to define a service, use get instead of invoke.
expect($injector.get($state.current.resolve.data)).toBe('findAll');

Comment: if you use something like karma with your jasmine tests you could use html2js preprocessor (https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html2js-preprocessor). This will make dealing with your templates/views a lot easier and could even remove this line from above: templateCache.put('template.html', '');

Comment: actually if you are using angular there is an specific module https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor which will allow you load templates as a `module('template/path.html')`

Comment: I followed the above code with adjustments to`andReturn` like mentioned in the above comment. However, my $state.current.name returns an empty string. Anybody knows why?

Comment: @Philip I am facing the same problem `$state.current.name` is empty string.

Comment: @Joy @VLeong I had this same problem, then realized it was due to the ui-router utility I'm writing was using ES6 promises instead of `$q`. Everything must use `$q` promises in order for `$rootScope.$digest()` to resolve all promises. My case is probably pretty unique, but thought I'd share just in case.

Comment: @Joy I was getting the same problem with $state.current.name returning an empty string. I had to replace $rootScope.$digest( ) with $httpBackend.flush( ). Following that change, I got what I expected.

Comment: What if the state is `abstract`? How would you test the `resolve` data? You cant do `$state.go()` in case of `abstract`.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to check only the current state's name it's easier to use `$state.transitionTo('splash')`

```
it('should transition to splash', inject(function($state,$rootScope){
  $state.transitionTo('splash');
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect($state.current.name).toBe('splash');
}));
```

Comment: To keep it simple I find this answer the most acceptable. Having test is nice and all, but having to write a test which is longer then my entire ui-route definition just to test a single end-point is just way to inefficient. In any case I'm voting this up

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is slightly off topic, but I came here from Google looking for a simple way to test a route's template, controller, and URL.

```
$state.get('stateName')
```

will give you

```
{
  url: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  controller: '...',
  name: 'stateName',
  resolve: {
    foo: function () {}
  }
}
```

in your tests.

So your tests could look something like this:

```
var state;
beforeEach(inject(function ($state) {
  state = $state.get('otherwise');
}));

it('matches a wild card', function () {
  expect(state.url).toEqual('/path/to/page');
});

it('renders the 404 page', function () {
  expect(state.templateUrl).toEqual('views/errors/404.html');
});

it('uses the right controller', function () {
  expect(state.controller).toEqual(...);
});

it('resolves the right thing', function () {
  expect(state.resolve.foo()).toEqual(...);
});

// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `state` that without `resolve`:

```
// TEST DESCRIPTION
describe('UI ROUTER', function () {
    // TEST SPECIFICATION
    it('should go to the state', function () {
        module('app');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $state, $templateCache) {
            // When you transition to the state with $state, UI-ROUTER
            // will look for the 'templateUrl' mentioned in the state's
            // configuration, so supply those templateUrls with templateCache
            $templateCache.put('app/templates/someTemplate.html');
            // Now GO to the state.
            $state.go('someState');
            // Run a digest cycle to update the $state object
            // you can also run it with $state.$digest();
            $state.$apply();

            // TEST EXPECTATION
            expect($state.current.name)
                .toBe('someState');
        });
    });
});
```

**NOTE:-**

For a nested state we may need to supply more than one template.  For ex. if we have a nested state `core.public.home` and each `state`, i.e. `core`, `core.public` and `core.public.home` has a `templateUrl` defined, we will have to add `$templateCache.put()` for each state's `templateUrl` key:-

`$templateCache.put('app/templates/template1.html');
$templateCache.put('app/templates/template2.html');
$templateCache.put('app/templates/template3.html');`

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$state.$current.locals.globals` to access all resolved values (see the code snippet).

```js
// Given
$httpBackend
  .expectGET('/api/users/123')
  .respond(200, { id: 1, email: 'test@email.com');
                                                       
// When                                                       
$state.go('users.show', { id: 123 });
$httpBackend.flush();                            
       
// Then
var user = $state.$current.locals.globals['user']
expact(user).to.have.property('id', 123);
expact(user).to.have.property('email', 'test@email.com');
```

In ui-router 1.0.0 (currently beta) you could try to invoke `$resolve.resolve(state, locals).then((resolved) => {})` in the specs. For instance https://github.com/lucassus/angular-webpack-seed/blob/9a5af271439fd447510c0e3e87332959cb0eda0f/src/app/contacts/one/one.state.spec.js#L29

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in anything in the content of the template, you could just mock $templateCache:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache) {
        spyOn($templateCache,'get').and.returnValue('<div></div>');
}
```