# Unit Testing ui-router with Invalid Route

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

Using this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21078955/409976) for adding unit tests for ui-router, I added the following test:

```
describe 'State: myApp', ->

  # load the filter's module
  beforeEach module 'myApp'

  $rootScope = $state = {}
  beforeEach inject ['$rootScope', '$state', (_$rootScope_, _$state_) ->
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_
    $state = _$state_
    ]
```

This test succeeds since accessing the `home` state results in hitting the `/` url.

```
  it "should return the '/' url for the 'home' state", ->
    expect($state.href('home')).toEqual '/'
```

However, when I test for an invalid route, I get `null`. The test succeeds:

```
  it "should return the '/' url if a URL cannot be constructed", ->
    expect($state.href('FOO_BAR_BAZ')).toEqual null
```

Consider these [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options):

> Note: returns null if no valid url can be constructed.

However, my app contains the following code to re-route an invalid state to `/`:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'
```

As a result, should this test still return `null`? Or should it return `/`?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'
```

is indeed making it return `/`

You will either want to deal with invalid urls by listening to the $rootScope broadcast $stateChangeError and remove your defaulting to `/`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(){})
```

OR

Use the defaulting to / with:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'
```

I don't think you can have both at the same time.