# Unit Testing Query Params for ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21078955/409976) explains how I can test ui-router for a particular `:id`:

```
  it('should respond to URL', function() {
    expect($state.href('state', { id: 1 })).toEqual('#/state/1');
  });
```

How can I pass in a query parameter for a unit test?

Example:

```
$stateProvider:
   $state("foo") {
       url: "/foo?myParam1
```

How can I test for the `foo` state with a passed-in query parameter of `myParam1=bar`?

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should respond to URL with params', function() {
  expect($state.href('foo', { myParam1: 'bar' })).toEqual('#/foo?myParam1=bar');
});
```

Then your routes would look like

```
$stateProvider
  .state("foo") {
    url: "/foo?:myParam1"
  }
```