# Testing angular ui-router state urls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

Trying to write just the most basic tests for a ui-router and running into some issues.  I have referred to [Angular ui router unit testing (states to urls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433485/angular-ui-router-unit-testing-states-to-urls) and a related blog post http://bardo.io/posts/testing-your-ui-router-configuration/, but cannot get a simpler version of what is explained there working.  Below is the code implementing the state I would like to test.  It works correctly in the browser.

```
# routes.coffee 
angular.module('waffle', ['ui.router']).config([
  '$stateProvider'

  ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state 'app.board.settings.edit-github-enterprise-source',
      url: '/sources/:source/edit'
      templateUrl: "/settings/sources/edit/github.html"
      controller: "SettingsEditSourceController as controller"
])
```

The associated test file with karma/mocha:

```
# routes-spec.coffee
describe 'routes', ->
  describe 'app.board.settings.edit-github-source', ->
    beforeEach module 'waffle'

    beforeEach inject (@$state, $templateCache) ->
      $templateCache.put '/settings/sources/edit/github.html', ''

    it 'should respond to URL', ->
      console.log @$state.get 'app.board.settings.edit-github-source' # log: null
      console.log @$state.includes 'app.board.settings.edit-github-source' # log: undefined

      @$state.href 'app.board.settings.edit-github-source', source: '1234'
      .should.equal '/sources/1234/edit'
```

The test fails saying `Cannot read property 'should' of null`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think it is just a matter of paranthesis placement at `@$state.href 'app.board.settings.edit-github-source', source: '1234'
      .should.equal '/sources/1234/edit'`. The `.should.equal '/sources/1234/edit'` is I think executed on the string `'1234'`.

Comment: In that case the error would be `expected '1234' to equal '/sources/1234/edit'`. I verified that the coffee is being compiled as expected.

Comment: Turns out I was doing everything right, but our `Grunftile.coffee` had `excludeShallow: ["routes"]` in the `compileTest` options