# How to inject $state correctly for angular ui router unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I am trying to write Unit-Tests for the following use case:

A http-request responds with an unathorized http-status(401) -> change state to login

The Problem is, that I dont even get the correct $state parameter injected into my test.

```
describe('Login: ', function() {
beforeEach(module('myapp'));


function mockTemplate(templateRoute, tmpl) {
    $templateCache.put(templateRoute, tmpl || templateRoute);
}

describe('On HTTP 401', function(){
    var state;

    beforeEach(function(){
        mockTemplate.bind('components/splitapp/splitappView.html', '')
        mockTemplate.bind('components/splitappMaster/splitappMasterView.html', '')
        mockTemplate.bind('components/splitappDetail/splitappDetailView.html', '')
        mockTemplate.bind('components/splitapp/offcanvasMenu.html', '')
    })


    it('Should go to login-state', inject(function($state, $location){
        console.log($location.url())
        $state.go("splitapp")
        console.log($state.current)
        expect($state.is('splitapp')).toEqual(true);
    }))
})
});
```

After $state.go the state should be splitapp, which is defined correctly in the router config. Heres my testrunner output

```
LOG: ''
LOG: Object{name: '', url: '^', views: null, abstract: true}
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.10.2) Login:  On HTTP 401 Should go to login- 
state FAILED
    Expected false to equal true.
    Error: Expected false to equal true.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found a solution: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433485/angular-ui-router-unit-testing-states-to-urls). The crucial part is **$rootScope.$digest()**. Has anyone an understandable description for what this function does?

Comment: In a nutshell, the function makes angular start processing stuff.  Lots of $state.transitionTo stuff happens asynchronously, and you need give angular a nudge to make this happen.