# Trouble testing state transition in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to write a test for an Angular app using ui-router similar to that suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/21078955/270511.

```
it('should transition to state', inject(function($rootScope, $state, $log) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    $log.error('$stateChangeError: ', error);
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', function(ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    $log.error('$stateNotFound: ', error);
  });

  var caseId = 1;
  $state.go('case.summary', { id: caseId }, { notify: true, reload: true });
  $rootScope.$digest();
  $log.debug('$state.current.name: ' + $state.current.name);
  expect($state.current.name).toEqual('case.summary');  // fails
  expect($state.is('case.summary', { id: caseId })).toBeTruthy(); // fails
}));
```

But this test fails.

`summary section
    ✓ should respond to URL
LOG LOG: 'debug: caseSvc.get, url: ,http://52.2.224.42:3000/cases/1'
LOG LOG: 'debug: $state.current.name: '
    ✗ should transition to state
    Expected '' to equal 'case.summary'.`

Nevertheless, this test succeeds:

```
it('should respond to URL', inject(function($state) {
  expect($state.href('case.summary', { id: 1 })).toEqual('#/cases/1/summary');
}));
```

Currently trying to trace this in the Chrome debugger.

I'm pretty stumped at this point.

Comment: Does the `case.summary` state resolve any data prior to entering the state? (or show us the configuration for your state)

Answer (score 0):

$state.go() returns a promise that needs to be waited upon.

Instead of

```
$state.go('case.summary', { id: caseId }, { notify: true, reload: true });
expect ...
```

I had to write

```
  $state.go(stateName, { id: caseId }, { notify: true, reload: true })
  .then(function() {
    $rootScope.$digest();
    $log.debug('$state.current.name: ' + $state.current.name);
    expect($state.current.name).toEqual(stateName);
    expect($state.is(stateName, { id: caseId })).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

In fact, the 3rd argument to $state.go isn't necessary, either.